# two regex patterns, can they be one?

Tags: java, regex

I have two regular expressions that I use to validate Colorado driver's license formats.

```
[0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}
```

and

```
[0-9]{9}
```

We have to allow for only 9 digits but the user is free to enter it in as 123456789 or 12-345-6789.

Is there a way I can combine these into one? Like a regex conditional statement of sorts?  Right now I am simply enumerating through all the available formats and breaking out once one is matched. I could always strip the hyphens out before I do the compare and only use `[0-9]{9}`, but then I won't be learning anything new.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a straight combine,

```
(?:[0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{9})
```

or to merge the logic (allowing dashes in one position without the other, which may not be desired),

```
[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}
```

(The brackets around the hyphens in your first regex aren't doing anything.)

Or merging the logic so that both hyphens are required if one is present,

```
(?:\d{2}-\d{3}-|\d{5})\d{4}
```

(Your `[0-9]`s can also be replaced with `\d`s.)

Comment: Second version allows one dash, which I believe is not the desired result.

Comment: Thank you.  Testing your examples here: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm gave me the exact results I wanted.  Also, thanks for the tips on [-] and \d.

Comment: Which version did you end up using?

Comment: I used: (?:\d{2}-\d{3}-|\d{5})\d{4}

Answer (score 6):

How about using a backreference to match the second hyphen only if the first is given:

```
\d{2}(-?)\d{3}\1\d{4}
```

Although I've never used regexes in Java so if it's supported the syntax might be different.  I've just tried this out in Ruby.

Comment: +1: I wouldn't use it for this case, but I like the tricksyness.

Comment: The syntax is the same in Java, but if you write it in the form of a String literal you'll have to escape the backslashes: "\\d{2}(-?)\\d{3}\\1\\d{4}"

Answer (score 3):

A neat version which will allow either dashes or not dashes is:

```
\d{2}(-?)\d{3}\1\d{4}
```

The capture (the brackets) will capture either '-' or nothing. The \1 will match again whatever was captured.

Comment: In addition, you can tell what format it was later by looking at $1 (at least in Perl). I'd never thought of that device.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}
```